# Can't access function from main file from header file C++

Tags: c++, scope

I don't know why I can't access the function clearConsole() from my .cpp file from the header files, I guess I'm calling it wrong? How do I target the main file from a header file? I try to call the clearConsole() function after the user input in the addCustomer() functinon in customer.h.

Main.cpp

```
// OTS.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "customer.h"

// Clear function specific to Windows 
// Cross platform alternatives are more convoluted to reach desired effect, so have not been included
void clearConsole()
{
    #ifdef _WIN32
    system("cls");
    #endif
}
```

Customer.h

```
//customer.H
//The object class customer

   class customer
    {
    //...
    clearConsole();
    }
```

Comment: Why have you put lots of code in that .h file? More normal would be to have a .h and a .cpp file.

Comment: What error did you hit? Is it a compiler error or a linker error? Do your files reside in the same folder? If they reside in different paths did you add those files to the project?

Comment: I was going to have each class in a seperate header file then the menu will be in the .cpp and also everything will be called from the .cpp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your files are linked together, a forward declaration of the functions should be enough.

**Customer.h**

```
//customer.H
//The object class customer

void clearConsole(); // <--- declare function

class customer
{

//....

};
```

But this structure looks wrong. I would declare the function in a different header, inside a `namespace`, and define it in a corresponding implementation file:

**clearconsole.h**

```
namespace ConsoleUtils
{
    void clearConsole();
}
```

**clearconsole.cpp**

```
namespace ConsoleUtils
{
    void clearConsole()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man :) Is this the best way to access and define functions that will be used throughout the project?

Answer (score 0):

Move your clearConsole() method to the header file (I think is not under discussion the implementation under .header files that I actually disagree, but anyway...), and change the system message to the specific one you need, as follows:

```
#ifndef _WIN32
#include <syscall.h>
#endif

void clearConsole(){
    #ifdef _WIN32
    system("cls");
    #else
    system("clear");
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem in my kernel that I'm writing in C,C++, and Assembly. I was able to fix this problem by telling the `ld` command to allow shared variables and functions using the `-shared` flag. In gcc you would just do the same thing because gcc is a linker, assembly, c compiler and a c++ compiler.